# Asscoiative array in php MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a mysql query in php:

```
mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM `content` WHERE `page`='$cont_sel_e['name']'")
```

However it does not return anything. I know that the error are the single quotes in the `'$cont_sel_e['name']'` part. The question is, how do I format it correctly, so that it works?

Comment: Use concatenation: `"SELECT * FROM \`content\` WHERE \`page\`='".$cont_sel_e['name']."'"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not actually need all those quotes.

`mysqli_query($link, "select * from content where page = '{$cont_sel_e['name']}'");`

That will work just fine